# HTTP insecure request to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

Is there a way to have insecure HTTP request (no HTTPS) to lambda? I can't use API Gateway because it uses just https, I can't use Load Balancer beacause it lets just 1 MB and I have a body request of 3 MB.
Is there a tool of AWS or other services to do it?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the problem with using API Gateway via HTTPS?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901263/10692493